# app is killed after click on windows button

Tags: windows, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

I am developing an windows runtime app for phone. 
I just wondering why my app is killed after I clicked windows button? According to msdn it says app will just be suspended, what implementation do I need to keep is suspended and when user click on back button on hardware, it will stay there.

Comment: Your app probably gets an exception when suspending and thus it's terminated. Have you debuged it (especially the suspension procedure)?

Comment: @Romasz indeed the suspensionManager.saveAsync() is throw exception. I just commented it out, it worked.

Comment: Commenting out this line may not be a good idea (depends on your app). Better try to find out why this had happened, check if it's not a serialization problem.